# Printing dict is not showing expected output

Tags: python, dictionary

This is the dict data(headers) I am using for REST API get call.

```
column="name"
order="descending"
headers = {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'orderby': '{"'+column+'":"'+order[:4]+'"}',
        }
print(headers)
```

This gives me following output:

```
{'accept': 'application/json','orderby': '{"\'name\'":"desc"}'}
```

I am getting 400- BAD Request because of this error in header.

I am expecting the following output that is without '(slash)' in second key-value pair.

How to print this expected output?

```
{'accept': 'application/json','orderby': '{"name":"desc"}'}
```

Comment: Why are you expecting that? The value of `orderby` is a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: If you want the `'orderby'` value to be a dict, then you need to assign a dict to it, rather than a string that coincidentally includes curly braces.  `'orderby': {column: order[:4]}` perhaps.

Comment: The value of orderby is dict which is used in REST API call

Comment: Specifically, I think what you want is a *JSON-encoded* dict (i.e. a dict that is encoded to a string in a specific way).

Comment: I don't get the output you show when I try your code.

Comment: I get what you say is the desired output.

Comment: There's a syntax error: a missing comma after the value for `'accept'`. Secondly, the code shows `"name"` but the outputs show `"severity"`. Accounting for those, this code doesn't reproduce the issue; the output is in the expected format: `{'accept': 'application/json', 'orderby': '{"name":"desc"}'}`. However, I believe you *actually* want a nested dict, like Jason said.

Comment: `order[:4]` also doesn't seem right. I suspect you want `asc` or `desc`, but you'll get `asce` instead of `asc`.

Comment: @wjandrea I edited the code. I didn't do copy paste as I did not want to put all data. SO it's just a writing mistake by human.

Comment: @Priya Ah, OK. But the output still doesn't match. Please make a [mre]. BTW, for more tips, like how to write a good title, see [ask].

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you for the tips. I will ask in as better way next time. I am not used to this so.

Comment: The issue is resolved. Actually, the column variable I was passing was already like this 'name'. So it was giving the above output in my code. It was like: column= "'name'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading between the lines a bit, it looks like what you're trying to generate for the `orderby` value is a JSON-encoded version of the dictionary `{column: order[:4]}`.  Rather than try to build this yourself with string interpolation I strongly suggest using the built-in `json` module, which will handle all the formatting for you (including how to quote the string values, escape them appropriately, etc):

```
import json

column = "severity"
order = "descending"
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'orderby': json.dumps({column: order[:4]})
}

print(headers)
```

```
{'accept': 'application/json', 'orderby': '{"severity": "desc"}'}
```

Comment: This is the better way for formatting. Using this now. Thank you so much :)